# Cannot find Preferences > Build, execution and deployment > Gradle > Runner >Delegate IDE build/run actions to cradle on Windows

Tags: android, dagger-2

I am reading [this](https://medium.com/@harivigneshjayapalan/dagger-2-for-android-beginners-dagger-2-part-i-f2de5564ab25) post about using Dagger-2 in Android apps and it's asking me to check the following configuration in Preferences.

`Preferences` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Gradle` -> `Runner` ->`Delegate IDE build/run actions to cradle`

I am on windows so I went the following path

`Settins` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Gradle`

But there is no `Runner` here

Comment: These are instructions for IntelliJ Idea, you should not need any of this with AS